# what is the PPA's OpenPGP ID?

Tags: ppa, live-cd, openpgp

I'm creating a LiveCD from [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch) guide and came across a line I do not understand:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 12345678 
#Substitute "12345678" with the PPA's OpenPGP ID.
```

wondered if anyone can explain what should I substitue 12345678 with and how to obtain it

Answer (score 4):

The information is listed on the ppa page in launchpad

Sample screenshot :

[image]

So , using the above as an example

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A9E345C0
```

See [PPA FAQ](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA#Your_PPA.27s_key) and [Ubuntu wiki secure apt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt) for details